# Проблемы с UPDATE mysql не редактирует записи

Tags: php, update

То работает то не работает, не пойму в чем проблема. посмотрите код. в последнее время перестал обновлять записи.

```
    if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) { //Проверяем, передана ли переменная на редактирования
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) { //Если новое имя предано, то обновляем и имя и цену
        $sql = mysql_query('UPDATE `mtu4` SET '
                .'`name` = "'.$_POST['name'].'",'
                .'`regis` = '.$_POST['regis'].','
                .'`relat` = '.$_POST['relat'].','
                .'`birth` = '.$_POST['birth'].','
                .'`uch` = '.$_POST['uch'].','
                .'`street` = '.$_POST['street'].','
                .'`home` = '.$_POST['home'].','
                .'`kvart` = '.$_POST['kvart'].','
                .'`pasp` = '.$_POST['pasp'].','
                .'`bio` = '.$_POST['bio'].','
                .'`jer` = '.$_POST['jer'].','
                .'`soz` = '.$_POST['soz'].','
                .'`work` = '.$_POST['work'].','
                .'`phone` = '.$_POST['phone'].' '
                .'WHERE `id` = '.$_GET['red_id']);
    }
if ($sql) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "<p>Произошла ошибка 1</p>";
}
}
```

Comment: Может вас уже давно взломали ? с такой подстановкой переменных полученных снаружи прямо в запрос SQL-инъекция делается за минуту. перейдите на использование PDO или mysqli и используйте привязываемые переменные. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 0):

Очень смелый подход к составлению запроса, нужно очень доверять своим пользователям.
Возможно, проблема в том, что строковые не заключены в одинарные кавычки. Попробуйте так:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `mtu4` SET 
            `name` = '".$_POST['name']."',
            `regis` = '".$_POST['regis']."',
            `relat` = '".$_POST['relat']."',
            `birth` = '".$_POST['birth']."',
            `uch` = '".$_POST['uch']."',
            `street` = '".$_POST['street']."',
            `home` = '".$_POST['home']."',
            `kvart` = '".$_POST['kvart']."',
            `pasp` = '".$_POST['pasp']."',
            `bio` = '".$_POST['bio']".',
            `jer` = '".$_POST['jer']."',
            `soz` = '".$_POST['soz']."',
            `work` = '".$_POST['work']."',
            `phone` = '".$_POST['phone']."' 
            WHERE `id` = ".$_GET['red_id']);
```